# Use of Intent fileters with Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

What are specifics and difference between usages of intent-filters and the property `android:exported="false"` while using Broadcast Receivers?

If we specify some intent-filters in `<receiver>` tag then this activity will receive all the intents regardless of the specified intent-filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:exported` just indicates whether the class can be called by other applications or not. If you don't need it to be called by other applications, you can safely put it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Merlin has already answered the exported part of your questions.

About intent-filters: All broadcast events that fit one of your intent-filters will cause your onReceive method to be called. The intent is passed into the method. So you can check which type of event triggered the receiver, if necessary.

Comment: I too got answer of my question. Specifically, when we are giving andorid:exported="false" and still supply some intent-filters with <intent-filter> in AndroidManifest.xml file then implicit broadcast intents from local activities can be received.